# Linq Distinct with a single comparison class (and interface)

Tags: linq, interface, distinct, iequalitycomparer, iequatable

I have several classes in my application, all of which have a `Name` property that I want to use as my basis for comparison (`Distinct()`, etc.).  Since I am always going to be comparing on `Name`, I decided to extract an interface, `ISomeComparedStuff`, which simply has a `Name` propery that all my other classes implement.  I set up a comparison class as such:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<ISomeComparedStuff>
{
     public bool Equals(ISomeComparedStuff x, ISomeComparedStuff y)
     {
          return x.Name == y.Name;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(ISomeComparedStuff obj)
     {
          return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

The only problem is when I try to code against it:

```
public class SomeStuff : ISomeComparedStuff
{
  ...
}

public class SomeMoreStuff : ISomeComparedStuff
{
  ...
}

var someStuff = GetSomeStuff().Distinct(new MyComparer);
var someMoreStuff = GetSomeMoreStuff().Distinct(new MyComparer);
```

I am getting a cast error (`SomeStuff` to `ISomeComparedStuff`).  Is there some way to do this so I only need one compare class, otherwise I'd have to create one for every one of my classes (even though I am always going to compare on `Name`)?

Note:  I understand this question "title" needs help.  Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good solution or not, but how about making MyComparer a generic class?

```
public class MyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    where T: ISomeComparedStuff
{
     public bool Equals(T x, T y)
     {
      return x.Name == y.Name;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(T obj)
     {
      return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

Downside is you have to new up an appropriate version:

```
var someStuff = GetSomeStuff().Distinct(new MyComparer<SomeStuff>());
var someMoreStuff = GetSomeMoreStuff().Distinct(new MyComparer<SomeMoreStuff>());
```

Expanding a bit, you could also make a new extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctByName<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values)
    where T: ISomeComparedStuff
{
    return values.Distinct(new MyComparer<T>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
var someStuff = GetSomeStuff().Cast<ISomeComparedStuff>().Distinct(new MyComparer);
```

Or use the non-generic `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: I like this approach (especially if it were encapsulated in another extension method, eg DistinctByName()), but you would have to cast the elements back to the original type otherwise the resulting `IEnumerable<ISomeComparedStuff>` is probably pretty useless.

Comment: Yes.  I would be concerned that I would lose all the data after the cast.

Comment: You don't lose any data. Casts to an interface aren't lossy.

Comment: Not lossy, but like I said, you would have to upcast back to the original type otherwise you can't easily access the other data.